# Reference a cell by its column name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update the contents of a cell in a workbook. My code looks a little like this:

```
ProductionWorkBook.Sheets("Production Schedule").Cells(StartRow, 1).Value = EstJobName(i)
```

The cells are referenced using `Cells(StartRow, 1)` Where StartRow was a pre-declared and pre-defined integer variable that specifies the row and "`1`" denotes the column.

EDIT: 
Now, I want to change this code to reference the columns by the **column HEADERS** instead.

For example, the header of a column is: "Fab Hours Date", how do I reference that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can simply use the letter name for the column in quotes:

```
Cells(StartRow, "A")
```

Edited to answer your further question:
to look for a specific column name, try this:

```
columnNamesRow = 1           ' or whichever row your names are in
nameToSearch = "Fab Hours"   ' or whatever name you want to search for
columnToUse = 0
lastUsedColumn = Worksheets("Foo").Cells(1, Worksheets("Foo").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For col = 1 To lastUsedColumn
   If Worksheets("Foo").Cells(columnNamesRow, col).Value = nameToSearch Then
      columnToUse = col
   End If
Next col


If columnToUse > 0 Then
' found the column you wanted, do your thing here using "columnToUse" as the column index
End If
```

Comment: Unbelievable.. I tried the same thing and kept giving me subscript out of range errors.. Turns out I was referencing the wrong spreadsheet.. Thanks much Vicky. This definitely solves my issues.

EDIT:
I Take that back!! :P I am actually trying to reference the **COLUMN HEADERS** not the column name.. I am extremely sorry for the confusion.

So, if the column header says "Fab Hours", How do I reference that in the code??

Comment: You'd have to iterate across the columns looking for the name you want. I'll edit my answer to include the code for this in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two different functions to get what you want. To use them, you'd have to put them in your code.

```
Function ColumnNumberByHeader(text As String, Optional headerRange As Range) As Long
    Dim foundRange As Range
    If (headerRange Is Nothing) Then
        Set headerRange = Range("1:1")
    End If

    Set foundRange = headerRange.Find(text)
    If (foundRange Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "Could not find column that matches header: " & text, vbCritical, "Header Not Found"
        ColumnNumberByHeader = 0
    Else
        ColumnNumberByHeader = foundRange.Column
    End If
End Function

Function ColumnNumberByHeader2(text As String, Optional headerRange As Range) As Long
    If (headerRange Is Nothing) Then
        Set headerRange = Range("1:1")
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    ColumnNumberByHeader2 = WorksheetFunction.Match(text, headerRange, False)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not find column that matches header: " & text, vbCritical, "Header Not Found"
        ColumnNumberByHeader2 = 0
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Example Calls:

```
 ColumnNumberByHeader ("Extn")
 ColumnNumberByHeader("1718", Range("2:2"))
```

Or in your case:

```
ProductionWorkBook.Sheets("Production Schedule"). _
Cells(StartRow, ColumnNumberByHeader("Fab Hours Date")).Value = EstJobName(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ProductionWorkBook.Sheets("Production Schedule").Range("A" & StartRow).Value = EstJobName(i)
```

Unless you mean the column is a named range you defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductionWorkBook.Sheets("Production Schedule").Range("E"& StartRow).Value = ...
```

will do the job.

Though keep in mind that using hard coded references like the column letter will risk that the macro breaks when the sheet is edited (e.g. a column is inserted). It's therefore better to use a named range and `Offset` to access:

```
ProductionWorkBook.Sheets("Production Schedule").Range("StartCell").Offset(StartRow-1).Value
```

Now you only need to provide the name `StartCell`to your fist cell (make sure that it's a local name in the Name Manager)